# Frequency Count for Twitter Data (Tweets)

Tags: python-2.7

I have been using python 2.7 for about a month (Newbie) on the weekends and I want to learn more and become better. My task is to find the frequency count of the top 50 words that are used on Twitter from a list of 3 (csv) files of data(tweets) that I have the collected. But remember, I want to remove the stop word from nltk.corpus import stopwords. I have only attempted to f = open  -1 of the csv files so far. Ideally I would like to do the other 2 csv files in this same script. But I wanted to get at least 1 working before I move onto the other 2 csv files.

```
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
import csv
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import wordpunct_tokenize
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import gutenberg
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.probability import *

tknzr = TweetTokenizer()
stop = stopwords.words("english")
#print(stop)

f = open ('tweets_table_favoritecount_top 50_test.csv')

#, encoding="utf8")

csv_f = csv.reader(f)
print(stopwords)

favoritecount = []
  for row in csv_f:
favoritecount.append(row[2])
  txt = str(row[2])
  print([i for i in txt.lower().split() if i not in stop])
for i in txt:
   fdist1 = FreqDist()
   print(fdist1.most_common(50))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I get a list like: ['rt', '@cbsbaltimore:', 'statement:', 'atty', 'ofc.', 'nero', 'hopes', '@baltimoresao', 'dismiss', 'charges', 'remain', '5', 'officers:', '#nerotrial', 'https://t.co\xe2\x80\xa6'], This is the output for the last line and this shows how it parsed the tweet into words. It shows what the tweet says minus the stop words. Great, but then I get a list of around 1400: []  - I am not getting only the top 50 words used over the entire csv file which contains around 1400 tweets.